# vmware virtual sockets vs cores per socket

Tags: vmware-esxi, socket, perfomance

VMware configuration give me various options for upgrade the cpu of the virtual machine.

- Number of virtual sockets
- Number of cores per socket

If I need 4 cpu in my linux box, which is better for perfomance, 4x1, 2x2, 1x4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They should be pretty much equal. My understanding is that those options exist for software that is licensed per socket.

Answer (score 3):

Technically there *will* some small variation but most of that will be based on your physical CPUs and their layout, your chipset and other load patterns. The only real way to be certain would be to benchmark each configuration - you may see 1-2% difference but there's a lot of effort to get to that.

Comment: I'd love to see more detail on how/why there is a performance difference w.r.t. VMWare.  e.g. doe VMWare actually use the socket/core definition to assign threads differently?